# react-redux state is not updated with new state in component using fetchById action but the redux-logger shows correct new state

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

i have react-App with Redux using axios. i have used `fetchById` action in a `courseDetails.jsx` component but the state is not updated with new value. As it take some time to get values from back-end using `fetchById` the component shows error due to the old state of previous component (lessons).The `redux-logger` shows the correct value in next state but the component is not updated with new state.
here is the `courseDetails.jsx` component code .

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { Link,useParams,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from "../_actions/courseActions";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    display: 'flex',
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  card: {
    padding:10,
    marginTop:10,
    display: 'flex',
    flex:1,
  },
  cardAction: {
    display: 'block',
    textAlign: 'initial'
  },
  cardMedia: {
    width: 160,
  },
  
});

export default function CourseDetails(props) {
 
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const classes = useStyles();
  let {courseId}=useParams();
  let {courseTitle}=useParams();
  let history = useHistory()
const dispatch = useDispatch();
useEffect(() => {
  //call the action creator with dispatch
  //  and wait until the promise resolves
  actions.fetchById(courseId)(dispatch)
     setLoading(false);
}, []);

let  single= useSelector(state=>state.course.list)
    //const course=myList.filter(x=>x.courseId==courseId);
   console.log("course in courseDetails",single)

  return (
    <div>
    {loading === true ? (<em>Loading!please wait...</em>) : (
    <Card className={classes.card} variant="outlined">
    <CardContent>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
    {single.courseTitle} 
      </Typography>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
    {single.subject} 
      </Typography>
      <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
       Fee: {single.fee}
      </Typography>
      
     
      <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
      {parse(single.details)}
        <br/>
        updated on: {single.updatedOn}
       
        </Typography>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="primary">
      <div><br/>
      <Link to={`/CourseLessons/${courseId}`}
><Button size="small" variant="contained" color="secondary"> Free Lectures </Button> </Link>-----
      
 
      </div>
              </Typography>
           
    </CardContent>
   
    </Card>
    )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

the old state shows the list of lessons in `lessons.jsx` component .
the `CourseDetails.jsx` component is tried to be rendered and want to get single course to display in `let  single= useSelector(state=>state.course.list)` line , it generates error due to values of `lessons` in old state .
[image: console screenshot here]
here is the code of `coursActions.js`

```
export const fetchById = (id) => dispatch => {
    courseApi.course().fetchById(id)
      .then(response => {
          
          dispatch({
              type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_BY_ID,
              payload: response.data
          })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

here is `coursApi.js` code

```
import axios from "axios";
import config from 'config';
const baseUrl = `${config.apiUrl}/api/`

export default {

    course(url = baseUrl + `Courses/`) {
        return {
            fetchAll: () => axios.get(url),
            fetchById: id => axios.get(url + id),
            create: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord),
            update: (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updateRecord),
            delete: id => axios.delete(url + id)
        }
    }
}
```

here is `courseReducer.js` code.

```
import { ACTION_TYPES } from '../_constants';

const initialState = {
    list: []
    
}


 export const course=(state = initialState, action)=>{

    switch (action.type) {
     
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL:
            
            return {
                
                 ...state,
                list: [...action.payload]
            }
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_BY_ID:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [action.payload]
            }

        case ACTION_TYPES.CREATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                list: [...state.list, action.payload]
            }

       

        
            
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

here is the combinedReducer in rootReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import { authentication } from './authentication.reducer';
import { registration } from './registration.reducer';
import { users } from './users.reducer';
import {course} from '../_reducers/courseReducer';
import {lesson} from '../_reducers/lessonReducer';
import {student} from '../_reducers/studentReducer';
import {tutor} from '../_reducers/tutorReducer';
import {need} from '../_reducers/needReducer';
import {post} from '../_reducers/postReducer';
import { alert } from './alert.reducer';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  authentication,
  registration,
  users,
  course,
  post,
  need,
  lesson,
  student,
  tutor,
  alert
 
})

export default rootReducer;
```

here is the `store` code

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import {rootReducer} from '../_reducers';

const loggerMiddleware = createLogger();

export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(
        thunkMiddleware,
        loggerMiddleware

    )
    //window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()

);
```

Comment: What is the error?? And please provide more information about lessons.jsx

Comment: hi @amit when the component renders it uses the old state which is lessons.after rendering useffect is called and fetchbyId action is dispatched and state is updated in store but the component does not re-render .i think we should focus on 'useSelector' carefully or use alternative to useselector.

Comment: Hi @amit wadhwani in lessons.jsx fetchall action is used in lessonActions.js.but in courseDetails.jsx fetchById is used in courseActions.js. please look at the courseDetails.jsx component and workaround to display the state after the fetchbyid is dispatched.thanks for help and interest in my problem.

Answer (score 0):

it may be helpful for anyone.but may be better workaround other than which i am sharing.i used `setTimeout()`  after `fetchById` in `useEffect` that updated the state as desired  and solved my problem..the complete `courseDetails.jsx` is as follows:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {useDispatch,useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import { Link,useParams,useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from "../_actions/courseActions";
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    display: 'flex',
  },
  pos: {
    marginBottom: 12,
  },
  card: {
    padding:10,
    marginTop:10,
    display: 'flex',
    flex:1,
  },
  cardAction: {
    display: 'block',
    textAlign: 'initial'
  },
  cardMedia: {
    width: 160,
  },
  
});

export default function CourseDetails(props) {
 const [flag,setFlag]=useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const classes = useStyles();
  let {courseId}=useParams();
  let {courseTitle}=useParams();
  let history = useHistory()
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  actions.fetchById(courseId)(dispatch)
  setTimeout(()=>{
  setFlag(true)
  },2000)
  setLoading(false);
    
}, []);

  const single=useSelector(state=>state.course.list)


console.log("course in courseDetails",single[0])
console.log("flag",flag)







  return (
    <div>
    {loading === false && flag===true ? (
    <Card className={classes.card} variant="outlined">
    <CardContent>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
    {single[0].courseTitle} 
      </Typography>
    <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
    {single[0].subject} 
      </Typography>
      <Typography className={classes.title} color="textSecondary" gutterBottom>
       Fee: {single[0].fee}
      </Typography>
      
     
      <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
      {parse(single[0].details)}
        <br/>
        updated on: {single[0].updatedOn}
       
        </Typography>
      <Typography variant="subtitle1" color="primary">
      <div><br/>
      <Link to={`/CourseLessons/${courseId}`}
><Button size="small" variant="contained" color="secondary"> Free Lectures </Button> </Link>-----
      
<Link to={`/Enroll/${single[0].courseId}/${single[0].courseTitle}`}
><Button size="small" variant="contained" color="primary"> Enroll Now</Button>
  </Link><br/><br/>
 
      </div>
              </Typography>
              <Button   onClick={() => history.goBack()}
            size="small" variant="contained" color="secondary">
              back
            </Button>
              {/* <Link to={`/courses`}
><Button size="small" variant="contained" color="primary"> All courses</Button> </Link><br/>
               */}
    </CardContent>
   
    </Card>
    ):(<em>Loading!please wait...</em>) }
    </div>
  );
}
```